IK not tracking to target
I've been making an IK mechanical arm/connector for a project of mine, and I cannot get the bones to properly track to the target. Most of the bones have rotation constraints in the IK menu, but even without them, the rig refuses to track to certain positions and rotations. I have no idea why this would be happening, outside of some obscure IK setting somewhere. I have isolated the joint from the rest of my project, and it can be found in the following .blend file.


I don't think that you can control a long IK chain like that, maybe you should create several IK along the arm, also create some pole targets so that it knows how to bend the arms?

if you uncheck rotation in your ik, it works pretty well but...yes, you loose the control over the rotation
